# PROC CORR Pearson's for categorical variable

Tags: sas, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to find the Pearson correlation coefficient between weight and height for species `Pike` in `sashelp.fish`, but I'm having issues returning the results specifically for Pike. Here's my code:

```
proc corr data=sashelp.fish pearson;
var height width;
by species;
run;
```

And here's the error message:

`Data set SASHELP.FISH is not sorted in ascending sequence. The current BY group has Species = Whitefish and the next BY group has Species = Parkki`.

I tried using `PROC SORT` to sort the data by `Species`, but received the error message "User does not have appropriate authorization level for library `SASHELP`."

Thank you!

Comment: This would be  a better question if the title related to the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify an output dataset then SAS by default will overwrite the input data with the new sorted data. However you do not had write access to the `sashelp` library and can't replace the `sashelp.fish` dataset. You therefore need to create a new sorted output dataset that you can then run `proc corr` on:

Example using your temporary work library:

```
proc sort data = sashelp.fish out = work.fish;
  by species;
run;

proc corr data=fish pearson;
  var height width;
  by species;
run;
```